# Partially apply type constructor

Tags: f#

I have a type with a constructor taking two arguments:

```
type Foo = Foo of int * int
```

And I can call it with a tuple of `(int, int)`.

```
let foo = Foo(1,2)
```

But in my case I want to partially apply the constructor to use it in a pipe

```
let someFunc param =
    calculateSomeInt param
    |> Foo 42  //error
```

But this is not possible because the constructor cannot be called in curried form.

Is there some possibility to tell F# I want the constructor in curried form without having to define a new function `let fooCtr a b = Foo (a,b)`?

Comment: Nope, constructor cannot be partially applied cause it is not F# function. This won't help much, but you could try (x,y) ||> Foo

Comment: @PavelVoronin Actually just a normal pipe can be used here because `Foo` is a function that takes one tuple value: `(42, param) |> Foo`

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. The `let fooCtr a b = Foo (a,b)` approach you mentioned in your question is the only way to do this. (I would probably call it `makeFoo` or better yet `mkFoo` rather than `fooCtr` myself, since I feel that function names should be verbs, but that's personal style preference).

Answer (score 0):

rmunn's answer is correct, but I'd like to add a detail.

You can add the constructor as a parameter to the `make` function, so you can use `make` to partially apply any constructor which takes a pair (a 2-tuple) as parameter:

```
type TypeA =
    | A of int*int
    | B of int*string

type TypeB = 
    | C of int*float

// make : (('a * 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c)
let make t a b = t(a,b)

// x : int -> TypeA
let x = make A 1

// y : string -> TypeA
let y = make B 2

// z : float -> TypeB
let z = make C 3
```

In fact, it works with any function which takes a pair as parameter, so the name `make` is slightly misleading in this case.